# Redirect Django con paramentros

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

Estoy realizando una pasarela de pagos en Django y estoy intentando dividir el procedimiento en dos views, una realiza la llamada y obtiene la respuesta y la segunda procesa la respuesta.

ahora mismo mi código es algo así:

```
def comprar(self):
    ...
    result = realizar_compra(pedido,perfil,tarjeta_data,request)
    print(result)
    return redirect('confirmacion-compra',args={'respuesta':result,'perfil':perfil,'producto':producto})
```

y esta mi vista de respuesta:

```
@login_required
def confirmacion_pago(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'intranet/confirmacion_comprar.html',{'mensaje':'Pago realizado correctamente.','perfil':perfil,'producto':producto})
```

quiero mandarla la variable result a la segunda función para que compruebe los datos y maquete la página de respuesta para que así no haya forma de retroceder a la pantalla anterior o por defecto recargar la página y realizar nuevamente el pago.

Comment: Puedes usar el método redirect pasándole el nombre del view en vez de la URL al view, y en ese caso le puedes pasar argumentos tal y como te indica en la documentación oficial.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bajo mi punto de vista tienes dos opciones

- Mandar por redirect
- por httpResponse y con su context
  cuando mandas por redirect la vista debe recibir los argumentos
  ejemplo:

  return anotherView(request, username, range)

recibiendo:

```
def anotherView(request,username,range):
```

METODO DOS:

```
context={
{
'mensaje':'Pago realizado correctamente.',
'perfil':perfil,
'producto':producto
}
return render(request, 'intranet/confirmacion_comprar.html', context)
```

espero te sirva y suerte !!

Comment: el problema de render es que no modifica la URL, simplemente maqueta el template y te lo muestra, pero necesito cambiar la url para que al recargar no vuelva a enviar el formulario de compra y realice una segunda compra sin querer.

Comment: como te comente en mi rspuesta tienes dos metodos por el render y  return  redirect ('confirmacion-compra', username, range) donde username, range son argmentos o variables que pasas a tu funcion/vista

Comment: al usar el redirect de la forma que me dices no estoy pasandole objectos, estoy llamando a la url de esta forma: /confirmacion-compra/usuario/range1/ y lo que quiero en mandarle un objeto como request.